# Synaptic Manager not working

Tags: lubuntu, dropbox

I am a novice who has been trying to work my way through with Ubuntu. I have Lubuntu 12.04 version on my laptop. 
Synaptics manager had not been working since the day I changed over to Ubuntu about a year ago. Ever since, I have read a lot of advice on web but nothing has worked. When I try to install Synaptics... from software in lubuntu, it starts downloading 'nautilus-dropbox' and then after showing progress upto 100% or 70% it just sits there for hours on end; leaving it on to do it overnight also has not changed anything. 
Please guide me how do I make my laptop functional.

Thanks for your help.
Regards, Sheelkt

Answer (score 1):

If you are indeed using Lubuntu 12.04, you will not get updates or be able to install software from the Lubuntu Software Center or by means of `apt-get`.

The reason is that, unlike Ubuntu 12.04, Lubuntu 12.04 reached its End of Life some time in 2013. You can read more about that concept here: http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life. To quote from there:

> When an Ubuntu release reaches its “end of life” it receives
>   no further maintenance updates, including critical security
>   upgrades. We highly recommend that you upgrade to a recent
>   version of Ubuntu at this point.
>
> This command will print the exact status of your system.
>
> `ubuntu-support-status`

For more, please read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu/LTS

My advice to you is to make a Live USB of Lubuntu 14.04 LTS and try it on your machine without actually installing it. If all looks good, do an actual install.